# Creating indexes for Elasticquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Do I have to create indexes like this `Book::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);` for every model in my Laravel project?

I succesfully created `App\Law::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);`, but when I try to create `App\LawType::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);` it shows an error:

> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception with message
>   '{"error":{"
>   root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already
>   exists",
>   "index":"default"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already
>   ex ists","index":"default"},"status":400}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel only creates a single index, whose default name is `default` but a custom name can also be [configured via the settings](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent#setting-a-custom-index-name) called `elasticquent.default_index`.

After that, each model will be stored in a different type within that index [using `putMapping`](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent#indexes-and-mapping).